"Il voulait que ce frisson cessât de courir sur sa peau."
La phrase suivante (tirée de la traduction de La Fondation - Dan Abnett),  me parait étrange:

Il voulait que ce frisson cessât de courir sur sa peau.

Je me demande si les temps sont correctement utilisés.
Je m'attends plutôt, par exemple, à :

Il voulait que ce frisson cesse de courir sur sa peau.


Oui, c'est l'accord des temps classiques, parce que voulait est à un temps du passé, c'est correct.

L'imparfait du subjonctif est correctement utilisé ici, vouloir étant conjugué au passé (imparfait de l'indicatif). Il s'agit cependant d'un usage littéraire (très) soutenu et on ne lit plus guère aujourd'hui que le présent du subjonctif dans ce contexte.

C'est pourtant si joli :'-)

@RomainValeri Fallait-il que tu le commentasses ? ;-)
